# Include multiple PDFs with different size and additional text on one page

Tags: pdfpages, standalone, includegraphics

I have several PDF files containing vector graphics. They all have customized sized such that there is no white border present. Now I want to combine them on a single page with some additional text.

In the end it should look something like this:

[image]

What is the easiest solution to obtain this? I tried using the standalone class and insert the PDFs with \includegraphics, but standalone seems to ignore many formatting orders and I am unable to make the page look as I want. Maybe there are better solutions.

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is use any document type and just mess with the margins. For the other features you will find simple answers anywhere, that's one of the multiple possible choices:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{vmargin} % para editar los margenes
\setpapersize{USletter}
\setmargins{2cm}% margen izquierdo
{1.5cm}     % margen superior
{17cm}      % anchura del texto
{23.42cm}   % altura del texto
{10pt}      % altura de los encabezados
{1cm}       % espacio entre el texto y los encabezados
{0pt}       % altura del pie de página
{1cm}       % espacio entre el texto y el pie de página
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\centering \Huge Title

\begin{figure}[htbp]\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{imagefile}
    \caption{Figure 1 text}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{imagefile}
    \\Figure 2 text (but in text mode, not in caption)
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]\centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.2\textwidth}            
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{imagefile}
        \caption{Figure 3 text}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.485\textwidth}\centering            
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{imagefile}
        \\Figure 4 (in text mode)
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}            
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{imagefile}
        \caption{Figure 5 text}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Figures 3, 4 y 5}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

and I get something like this
[image: final result]